# Sorting array(NSArray) in descending order

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a array of NSString objects which I have to sort by descending.

Since I did not find any API to sort the array in descending order I approached by following way.

I wrote a category for NSString as listed bellow.

```
- (NSComparisonResult)CompareDescending:(NSString *)aString
{

    NSComparisonResult returnResult = NSOrderedSame;

    returnResult = [self compare:aString];

    if(NSOrderedAscending == returnResult)
        returnResult = NSOrderedDescending;
    else if(NSOrderedDescending == returnResult)
        returnResult = NSOrderedAscending;

    return returnResult;
}
```

Then I sorted the array using the statement

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [inFileTypes sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(CompareDescending:)];
```

Is this right solution? is there a better solution?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use NSSortDescriptor:

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending:NO selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];
NSArray* sortedArray = [inFileTypes sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

Here we use `localizedCompare:` to compare the strings, and pass `NO` to the ascending: option to sort in descending order.

Comment: since 'sortDescriptorWithKey' 10.6 aboveI have used following statement.
[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: nil ascending: NO];

thanks...

Comment: Indeed, I should have mentioned that – don’t forget the -autorelease though :)

Answer (score 10):

or simplify your solution:

```
NSArray *temp = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"b", @"c", @"5", @"d", @"85", nil];
NSArray *sortedArray = [temp  sortedArrayUsingComparator:
                        ^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){
                            //descending order
                            return [obj2 compare:obj1]; 
                            //ascending order
                            return [obj1 compare:obj2];
                        }];
NSLog(@"%@", sortedArray);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor; 
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"length" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
[wordsArray sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Using this code we can sort the array in descending order on the basis of length.